# Tagged questions

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, prepared-statement, query-performance

I have similar to StackExchange network that utilises **tagged questions**.

[image: database structure]

In my web application Users also can find `questions` by `tags`. The query below returns a set of tagged questions:

```
SELECT question.*, user_activity.* FROM question
    JOIN user_activity ON ua_id = qs_id
    JOIN question_tag ON qt_question_id = qs_id
    JOIN tag ON qt_tag_id = tag_id
WHERE tag_name IN (:tags)
GROUP BY qs_id
HAVING count(tag_id) >= :tagCount
```

Where `:tags` is array of tag names and `:tagCount` == count for this array.
In my opinion this query has bad practice even though it does things right.

Are there any ways to optimise this query?

Comment: Looks fine, however I would use an array of tag_id. That way, I believe, the query would work faster

Comment: @cha `tag_name` unique column.